# Text background color when breaking line

Tags: html, css

I want a background-color exactly behind my text.

Basically I solved it, but when the text is longer then the container div the background-color covers the whole width.

I've tried to play around with the `word-break` and `white-space` properties but I didn't found a good result.

Maybe someone can give me a hint.

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avGr6/1/)

[image] 

The covered area should be transparent

Regards

Comment: try span instead of div tag

Comment: Your need is not clear to me. A screenshot of what you need, maybe?

Comment: So because it's unclear downvote instead of asking? .. good idea.. i will provide 2 jsFiddle's..
@AVM span didn't changed anything

Comment: @AVM I guess you mean `<span>` instead of `<h3>`? and remove the `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: (I did not downvote yet :P)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/avGr6/2/ ? turn h3 inline and send margins to parents padding .

Comment: @GCyrillus exactly that. Thank you. PhistucK soz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turn `h3` `inline` and send `margin`s to parent's `padding` **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/avGr6/2/)**

Comment: Oh. I just see, that the lines are overlapping

Comment: line-height is too small, that's why :)